# Join with same table with three different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to join with same table with three different conditions. Below are the scenarios:

Table1 :

```
ID,NAME,INSERT_DT
```

Table2 :

```
ID_FK,DESC,REC_BEG_DT,REC_END_DT,REC_INDC,SYSTEM_CODE,SERVICE_SRT_DT,SERVICE_END_DT
```

Joining Conditions:

1.

```
Table1.ID=Table2.ID_FK
SYSTEM_CODE='ABC'
REC_INDC='A'
Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.SERVICE_SRT_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.SERVICE_END_DT
```

If no results return use join condition 2.
If the above condition return multiple results then pick the one that satisfy

```
Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.REC_BEG_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.REC_END_DT
```

2. Table1.ID=Table2.ID_FK
   SYSTEM_CODE='ABC'
   REC_INDC='A'

   If no results return use join condition 3.
   If the above condition return multiple results then pick the one that satisfy

   Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.REC_BEG_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.REC_END_DT
3. Table1.ID=Table2.ID_FK
   SYSTEM_CODE='ABC'

   If no results return Null.
   If the above condition return multiple results then pick the one that satisfy

   Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.REC_BEG_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.REC_END_DT

Adding sample input and output

Table1

[image: Table1]

Table2

[image: table2]

[image: Output]

Edit:
Added one more scenario

Tab1

|ID|NAME|INSERT_DT|

|1|XY|29/04/2021|

Tab2

ID_FK|DESC|REC_BEG_DT|REC_END_DT|REC_INDC|SYSTEM_CODE|SERVICE_SRT_DT|SERVICE_END

1|XY DESC1|1/4/2021|30/04/2021|I|ABC|1/3/2021|30/03/2021

1|XY DESC2|1/3/2021|30/03/2021|I|ABC|1/4/2021|30/04/2021

1|XY DESC2|1/3/2021|30/03/2021|I|ABC|1/3/2021|30/03/2021

Logically 1st record from table should be selected.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output in text format.

Comment: "If the above condition return multiple results then pick the one  that satisfy .." So the query must return no more then one row.  ?

Comment: Yes @Serg, it will return not more than one row

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I have added

Comment: To replicate the situation sample inputs need to be in text format instead of image. Please upload text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flag rows with optional conditions priority flags and select a row with the highest priority. A query template

```
select  ...
from
( 
    select  ... , 
        -- priority flags of optional conditions 
       row_number() over(partition by Table1_id order by 
        case when REC_INDC='A' then '0' else '9' end
        || case when Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.SERVICE_SRT_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.SERVICE_END_DT then '0' else '9' end
        || case when Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.REC_BEG_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.REC_END_DT then '0' else '9' end ) rn
    from ...
    where ...
         -- mandatory condition
        Table1.ID=Table2.ID_FK
        AND SYSTEM_CODE='ABC'
) t
where rn = 1
```

**EDIT**

To take all REC_INDC ='I' case into account

```
select *
from ( 
    select table1.INSERT_DT, table2.* , 
       f.flags,
       row_number() over(partition by Table1.id order by f.flags) rn
    from table1
    join Table2 on
         -- mandatory condition
        Table1.ID=Table2.ID_FK
        AND SYSTEM_CODE='ABC'
    cross join lateral(
        -- priority flags of optional conditions 
         select case when  REC_INDC='A' and Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.SERVICE_SRT_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.SERVICE_END_DT then '00' 
                 else 
                    case when REC_INDC='A' then '90' else '99' end end
                 || case when Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.REC_BEG_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.REC_END_DT then '0' else '9' end  flags
         from dual ) f 
     ) t
where rn = 1
```

Lateral is here just as a convinience, the exprssion can be easyly merged into SELECT list.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0978c9ba6949a6d3663783bb4b7eb0c6)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Serg. Can you please explain a bit more on priority flag, it would be really helpful.

Comment: For example, a row with '009' flag (REC_INDC='A' ) and (Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.SERVICE_SRT_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.SERVICE_END_DT ) will be prefered over  a row with 099 flag   (REC_INDC='A'  only).

Comment: This will not work in one scenario when all the REC_INDC ='I' and any of the data has Table1.INSERT_DT >= Table2.SERVICE_SRT_DT AND Table1.INSERT_DT <= Table2.SERVICE_END_DT, then it will pull incorrect data based on the order by condition @Serg

Comment: Please show sample data as text and required result for the case.

Comment: Added the data for the new scenario where the code is failing 
Logically record1 from tab2 should be picked up as per the 3rd join mentioned above, but it is picking 1st record from tab2 as it is producing 909 as flag @Serg